# How to update unique email address or other properties in asp.net mvc5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

In my asp.net mvc5 application user can update there email address or other data. When user create an account it works fine, but when I update date if the email field unchanged then validation message show "Email Address already exists". So how can I fix it?

I also need to check if email address change then it must check this email is unique or not. If not unique then user can't update the data and validation message show "Email Address already exists".

Script

```
$('#UserEmail').blur(function () {
  var url = "/Account/CheckUserEmail";
  var Email = $('#UserEmail').val();
  $.get(url, { input: email }, function (data) {
    if (data == "Available") {
      $("#result").html("<span style='color:green;'>User email available</span>");
      $("#UserEmail").css('background-color', '');
    } else if (data == "Empty") {
      $("#result").html("<span> </span>");
    } else {
      $("#result").html("<span style='color:red'>User email not available</span>");
      //$("#UserEmail").css('background-color', '#e97878');
    }
  });
})
```

Controller

```
public string CheckUserEmail(string email)
{
  if (input == string.Empty)
  {
    return "Empty";
  }
  var finduser = UserManager.FindByEmail(email);
  if (finduser == null)
  {
    return "Available";
  }
  else
  {
    return "Not Available";
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Are you using a `[Remote]` attribute? If so show you code!

Comment: i am following this tutorial http://www.itorian.com/2013/03/client-side-username-availability.html

Comment: We need to see **your** code

Comment: Also need your `CheckUserEmail` code

Comment: anything else you want to **see**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you do this as opposed to using the `[Remote]` attribute and let unobtrusive validation handle all this for you? Note also nothing in this code is preventing the form from being submitted (it just displays something)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you handling the `.blur()` event which would unnecessarily trigger your ajax call when a user tabs through the controls unchanged. Instead you should be handling the `.change()` event.  This would be triggered only when the text is changed and the control loses focus. A user could still make a change, then go back and undo it so you could prevent the server being called by comparing the `value` and `defaultValue`. Finally there seems no point calling the server if the user has not entered an email.

Script (note the `isValid` variable declared outside the function so this could be checked to prevent a submit)

```
var isValid = true;

$('#UserEmail').change(function () {
  var span = $('<span></span>');
  var url = '@Url.Action("CheckUserEmail", "Account")'; // don't hard code your url's
  var email = $(this).val();
  if(!email) { // assume an email address is required
    isValid = false;
    span.text('Please enter an email address');
  } else if (email == $(this)[0].defaultValue) { // nothing has changed so OK      
    isValid = true;
  } else { // call server to validate
    $.get(url, { input: email }, function (data) {
      isValid = data;
      if (!isValid) {
        span.text('User email not available');
      }
    });
  }
  if(isValid) { 
    span.css('color', 'green'); // better to use class names
  } else {
    span.css('color', 'red');
  }
  $("#result").html(span);
});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult CheckUserEmail(string email)
{
  return Json(UserManager.FindByEmail(email) == null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

However all this is rather fragile and doesn't prevent the form from being submitted. I would recommend using jquery unobtrusive validation along with the `RemoteAttribute` for checking if an existing email exists, and the `Required` and `EmailAttribute` for ensuring its a valid email address, then using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in the view.